# Shorten UILabel width to fit text given height

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am working on an app with some iMessage style messaging as part of it.

I have the height resizing working great, but now I would like to add some resizing for the width to make it more iMessage-y. I have a UILabel in a UIView.

This is what I have in mind:

This is what a certain cell looks like:

[image: what I currently have image]

I would like to now shorten the width of this UILabel so that I cut off the extra space on the right. It would look like this:

[image: what I want image]

Notice how there is less space on the right.

How can I shorten the UILabel's or at least the UIView's (container) width so that there is less space on the right? I need to do this dynamically because that extra space on the right in the first image changes depending on the text there, as do the number of lines.

Comment: Add the width constrain with 'less than' relationship (e.g. < 200) and remove height constraints to grow as necessary, auto-layout will take care of the rest, ah and don't set any trailing constraints.

Comment: @RJE, I didn't use constraints to grow the height. I calculated it using `.sizeForWidth(width:font:size:)`

Comment: you can use this method `let rect = (text as NSString).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: 200, height: 9000), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)], context: nil)` rect will give you the CGRect withing your width parameter

Comment: @RJE, why 200 and 9000?

Comment: Just random numbers. 200 is your width. You can use any number according to the screen width(you can dynamically calculate this width based on available screen size) . 9000 suppose to be a big number so height can grow freely.  :O